# CSS Animation doesn't work on older Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, animation, cross-browser

I'm not very familiar with css nor css animations. I have made a fade-in animation for some pictures. They do work great, but not on an old Safari browser.

A friend of mine uses Safari 5.1.10 and the pictures don't get displayed.

What can I do that it will play the animation **or** how can I tell the browser "if you're too old for that stuff then just ignore the animation and display the pictures"?

And here is the css:

```
 .column-image > div picture > img{
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(6) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(7) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}


#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(11) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 2s;
}


#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(12) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

 @keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "A friend of mine uses Safari 5.1.10 " — Tell them to stop. It was released in 2010. It doesn't get security updates. It doesn't support a lot of things used on the modern web.

Comment: yes, I did already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to add vendor prefixes to the animation attributes because in older versions they're considered 'experimental'. Check out the [support for Animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) on Can I Use? Safari 5.1 requires the -webkit- prefix.

You code should work when changed to the following:

```
.column-image > div picture > img{
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(6) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}

#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(7) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
}


#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(11) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}


#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(12) > div picture > img{
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The [`opacity`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity) attribute is okay and has pretty good support and that does not have a prefix to add. There are other vendor prefixes for other browsers too as you've used already, but you'll be fine with just the webkit prefix for the animation ones (*keep the prefixed **keyframe** prefixes though*).